# Spring Restful Service with Spring Boot - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data, spring-boot

I am trying to build a Spring RESTful Webservice. I have ended up in NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.

Could anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

**Packages**

- Entities - ch.example.entities.core
- repositories - ch.example.repositories
- service - ch.example.service

**ProfileRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface ProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<AbstractProfile, Long> {
}
```

**ProfileService**

```
public interface ProfileService {
    List<AbstractProfile> findAll();
}
```

**ProfileServiceImpl**

```
 @Service
 public class ProfileServiceImpl implements ProfileService {  

    @Autowired
    private ProfileRepository repository;

    @Override
    public List<AbstractProfile> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
 }
```

**ProfileController**

```
@RestController
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:META-INF/mysql-spring-context.xml")
public class ProfileController {
    @Autowired
    private ProfileService service;

    @RequestMapping("/profile")
    public List<AbstractProfile> getAllProfiles() {
        return service.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Spring ProfileApp**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan
public class ProfileApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProfileApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ch.example.repositories.ProfileRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**Spring-Context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.7.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Database -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/entrevista_db" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Entity Manager -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="m-entrevista" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Jpa Rep -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="ch.example.repositories">
    </jpa:repositories> 
        <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="ch.example.service"/>


    <bean id="service" class="ch.example.service.ProfileServiceImpl"></bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the spring-boot didn't load the spring-context.xml, where I had all the configurations. Therefore I have to modify my ProfileApp like this.

**Spring-Boot: Profile App**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/mysql-spring-context.xml")
public class ProfileApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProfileApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

That's all. It worked..

Comment: You may want to read up on Boot's auto-configuration support. Much of your XML configuration is unnecessary in Spring Boot and can be replaced with a handful of lines in `src/main/resources/application.properties`.

Comment: What is the use of doing with properties instead of context.xml? Will it perform better/faster?

Comment: It's about reducing the amount of configuration that you have to write and maintain. You're missing one of Boot's main benefits by configuring everything yourself. You should be able to replace all of the XML with Boot's auto configuration and a few lines in application.properties to configure the DataSource

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)
`@ComponentScan` -  Configures component scanning directives for use with @Configuration classes. Provides support parallel with Spring XML's `<context:component-scan>` element.
**One of basePackageClasses(), basePackages() or its alias value() must be specified.**

So change it to

```
@ComponentScan({"ch.example.repositories","ch.example.service"})
```

Comment: that's right. but when I changed it to @ComponentScan({...}), it didn't work. So i put this tag in my context.xml and then imported the XML resource. Then it worked

Comment: The documentation you've linked to is for an older version of Spring. In Spring 3.2 and later `@ComponentScan` doesn't require any packages to be specified and "if specific packages are not defined scanning will occur from the package of the class with this annotation." Spring Boot uses Spring 4.0 or 4.1 (depending on the version of Boot you're using).